# Unable to start npf driver

Tags: networking, drivers, wireshark

I need to start the npf driver for Wireshark but when I try to type "net start npf" in cmd prompt, I get the following error:

```
"System error 1058 has occurred. 
The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or has no devices associated with it."
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if you have [Winpcap](http://www.winpcap.org/install/default.htm) installed.

If yes, check if the service is started or not. If not start it.

There are two ways to do that, graphical method using **services.msc** & command line method using **[SC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssehgal/archive/2009/06/01/configuring-windows-services-using-command-prompt.aspx)**

**Check service status**

`SC QUERY NPF`

if it returns the service is stopped then run the command below

**Start the service**

```
SC CONFIG NPF START=AUTO/DEMAND
```

Choose auto or demand as per your need. Auto is for automatic & demand is for manual i.e. started when required